# Var_dump to string

Tags: php

i have a var_dump output from a curl post
i want to parse this var_dump output to stinrg

the var_dump output is like

```
a:3:{s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:3:"msg";s:32:"Transaction Fetched Successfully";s:19:"transaction_details";a:1:{i:100003105;a:9:{s:8:"mihpayid";s:7:"4169799";s:10:"request_id";N;s:12:"bank_ref_num";N;s:3:"amt";s:6:"349.00";s:4:"disc";s:4:"0.00";s:4:"mode";s:1:"-";s:7:"retries";i:0;s:6:"status";s:7:"pending";s:14:"unmappedstatus";s:9:"initiated";}}}
```

Comment: It's already a string, what do you want ?

Comment: Can you explain better your needs?
var_export($variable,true) avoid to send the output versus the web server

Comment: This is not a var_dump-output, it's a serialized array.

Answer (score 3):

It is the result of [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) , so what you need is  [unserialzie](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Answer (score 1):

An option is:

```
$myStringVar=var_export($var, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with `var_export`:

```
$stringDump = var_export($var, true);
```

`true` is used to return the string instead of echo.